# An unexplained overflow in C

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm writing code to find the longest row in the input stream and print it out. However, after I defined an int called max_count = 0, I always found an overflow, which displayed max_count as 1633771873. I've initialized that variable, so I don't know where the problem is. You probably do not need to figure out all of the functions, but each of them has its comment.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEFAULT 10

int getline(char line[], int limit);
void copy(char from[], char to[]);
int enlarge(int lim, char s[]);

main() 
{
    int i;
    int max_count = 0;
    char line[DEFAULT];
    char maxline[DEFAULT];
    while ((i = getline(line, DEFAULT)) != 0) {
        if (i > max_count) {    // where weird thing happend (max_count=1633771873)
            max_count = i;
            copy(line, maxline);
        }
    }
    if (max_count > 0) {
        printf("maxline: %s", maxline);
    } else {
        printf("No maxline");
    }
    return 0;
}

/*get a row from input stream and return its length*/
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
     int i, c;
     for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n'); ++i) {        
        if (i == lim - 1) {
            lim = enlarge(lim, s); 
        }
        s[i] = c;
     }
     if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
     }
     if (i == lim) {
        enlarge(lim, s); 
     }
     s[i] = '\0';
     return i;
}

/*copy an array to another */
void copy(char from[], char to[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (from[i] != '\0') {
        to[i] = from[i];
        ++i;
    }
}

/*expand an array twice as its capacity*/
int enlarge(int lim, char s[]) 
{   
    s[lim - 1] = '\0';
    lim *= 2;
    char temp[lim];
    copy(s, temp);
    s = temp;   
    return lim;
}
```

This is the console window:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
^Z
maxline: 
--------------------------------
Process exited after 15.19 seconds with return value 3221225477
```

Comment: `returns 3221225477` - you mean it _prints_ `maxline: 3221225477`? Please post the output of your program. Please post the input to your program.

Comment: Indeed. This program doesn't print max_count so how do you know what value max_count has? Are you using the debugger? (that is okay, but if yes, say so)

Comment: How do you magically expand the array to twice its capacity? It's length is `10` and that's that. You must use `malloc` and `realloc` to do that.

Comment: @user253751, yes, I used debugger and it told me that value

Comment: @Weather Vane Actually I modified the pointer to refer another bigger array. I didn't explain explicitly.

Comment: `This is the console window` - what compiler do you use? In what environment are you programming? OS? IDE?

Comment: You use a self-defined `getline()` function while including the standard function with `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: As it happens your "overflowed value" in hex is `61616161` which is ASCII values for `'a'`. You have buffer oveflow.

Comment: Apparently "return value 3221225477" is how some operating systems report a segfault. If you ran it on the command line it would say "Segmentation fault" which you can Google. (or "access violation" on Windows)

Comment: I'm using GCC as compiler and Dev C++ as my IDE. @KamilCuk

Comment: `#define DEFAULT 10` your buffers have only space for 9 characters. Those 3 lines: `char temp[lim]; copy(s, temp); s = temp;` make no sense - you are copying _from_ `temp` into `s`, then assigning `s` to `temp`... You can't "enlarge" a buffer with static size - `char line[DEFAULT];` has space for 10 bytes no matter what you do. The code has many unrelated errors. In `s[i] = c;` when `i = 10` you just write to the array out of bounds.

Comment: Re: [because an array represents an address instead of a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60040309/an-unexplained-overflow-in-c#comment106185745_60040851) --> Not quite: An _array_ is not a address/pointer.  An address/pointer is not an array.  There are related, yet not the same.

Comment: `if (i == lim - 1) {` is a problem when `lim == 0` as `enlarge()` is not called before it is needed.  Recommend `if (i + 1 >= lim) {`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a buffer with space for 10 characters:

```
#define DEFAULT 10
char line[DEFAULT];
```

You enter 37 characters including a newline:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Your `getline` function tries to store them all in `line` (by the way, `enlarge` doesn't do anything useful).

The first 10 characters fit into `line`. The other 27 characters and the terminating `'\0'` overwrite other random variables which come after `line` in memory.

That is why `max_count` holds the ASCII codes for `aaaa`.

Comment: My aim is to create a bigger buffer and copy the content from the smaller one to the bigger and then change the pointer to refer to the bigger array. Why doesn't my enlarge function make sense?

Comment: Because you're working on the stack and using VLA, as soon as the function returns your "new array" gets is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Your `enlarge` function isn't doing what you think it is.

```
int enlarge(int lim, char s[]) 
{   
    s[lim - 1] = '\0';
    lim *= 2;
    char temp[lim];
    copy(s, temp);
    s = temp;   
    return lim;
}
```

You're creating a new array `temp` within the scope of the function.  You then copy the address of the start of the array to `s`.  Since `s` is a parameter to the function, modifying `s` won't be reflected in the calling function.  So after this function returns `s` in `getline` is unchanged.

Even if you were to fix this by either returning a `char *` or changing the function to accept a `char **` and assigning `temp` to the dereferenced pointer, you would be returning the address of a variable local to `enlarge`.  That variable goes out of scope when the function returns and so the pointer would be invalid.

The only way you can change the size of an array is if you first allocate it dynamically with `malloc` and then later use `realloc` to change its size.

Also, `getline` is the name of a function on POSIX systems.   You should change the name to something else.

Comment: I agree with you mostly, but I just learned, when I pass an array to a function, that means I change the reference of s to another because an array represents an address instead of a value. So I'm all for your answer except your first paragraph. I don't know whether I'm right. @dbush

Comment: @SaeronMeng Yes, when you pass an array to a function you're actually passing the address of the first member.  However, `s` is still a local variable so changing `s` won't change anything in the caller.  It doesn't matter that the type is a pointer.  If you dereference a pointer and modify what it points to, then the caller will see that.

Comment: I get it. @dbush